# Can't use keyboard in Warcraft3 - PlayOnLinux

Tags: 11.10, playonlinux

I installed PlayOnLinux to play Warcraft 3 but when I come to the first screen of Warcraft3, I can't type anything. I mean the keyboard doesn't work. What's the problem?in

Comment: "Emulate a virtual desktop" caused others problems for me like the screens's bottom being cut off. I found that by, on PlayOnLinux, configuring it on "choose a new shortcut" to start a different .exe (war3.exe) in place of the former one solved all the problems. Keyboard not work on full screen.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you try it with the regular wine? With wine 1.4 it should work perfect.

If that does not work, try to remove the .wine directory in your homefolder ( before this save your important data from there) , and start over.

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to go to "Configure Wine". In Graphics tab, check "Emulate a virtual desktop".

Answer (score 0):

I just test with Warcraft 1.27b and have same issue with system Wine. Checked some version, and reading this winedb test : https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=3126&iTestingId=103476

Then i install via PlayOnLinux Wine 3.14, and keyboard come back on full screen ( `-opengl` is set on the launcher).